# VizFrame multiplies tooltip

Tags: sapui5

VizFrame multiplies tooltip when ones travels by clicking on some chart data:

```
this._oVizFrame.attachSelectData(jQuery.proxy(this._someFunction,this));
```

from one chart page to other and back, in some cases it works fine, but sometimes it multiplies tooltip as in this picture:

[image]

Everytime it adds one tooltip, when ones goes to other page and back. I tried to destroy tootlip as bellow, but nothing changed:

```
renderComplete: function() {  
   this._oVizFrame.destroyTooltip();
},
```

Do you have any idea, how to cope with this? This tooltip can be hidden but I would like to use it.

Thanks.

Comment: We used tooltips in many charts and never encountered this issue. How do you define your tooltip? I guess you don´t do it via vizProperties? If you show it yourself (via own coding), you should check for event handlers which are attached twice.

Comment: This is default native VizFrame tooltip. I just set it visible in the VizFrame properties. Are you using this also?